# Is "number (as in amount) of things" considered singular or plural?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I am more inclined to say that it is singular, so I rather form sentences like:

> The number of chairs is N.

I am not sure enough about it to insist about it, though. Is "is" correct? Is "are" correct, too? If one is yes and the other one's no, then is this generally the case, or does it depend on the other factors?

I repeat myself: *Is “number (as in amount) of things” considered singular or plural?*

Comment: Sorry for having a copy of title in the question body. It was added after having received a complaint and a downvote for question not being clear about in which sense the "number" is being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The number of chairs is N.

This sentence is singular because the verb **is** refers to **number** not **chairs**
"The number is N." The phrase **of chairs** is an adjective that modifies **number**.

Comment: I think that's the actual question, whether the word "number" is plural or singular (or does it vary depending on what it refers to).  You might want to clarify in your answer that it is *single*, and perhaps provide references and/or other examples to support this.  My feeling is that it varies (e.g. *"a **number** of the students **are** redheaded"*) so you might want to modify your answer to accommodate.

Comment: Andrew, can you provide an example where **number** is plural?

Comment: An example (different from the OP's): "A number of grammarians **have been** seen walking across the quad." Strictly speaking, the whole phrase is plural, not the word _number._ This is a messy topic, though. In the OP's sentence, _is_ agrees with _number_ (singular), just as you say.

Comment: I disagree with both examples provided by Andrew and Ben, that they do not seem to be apposite to my question. I clearly have stated that I am using "number" as in "amount". In both of those examples, however, the word "number" is used in place of "several". I am going to accept this answer, because it really answers my question: I was wondering whether "number (as in amount)" somehow is considered plural if it is referring to a number that is more than just 1.

Comment: A small correction: the phrase _of chairs_ functions as an adjective that modifies _number,_ not as an adverb.

Comment: @ThoAppelsin Oh, now I see. Could you please edit your question to add that information? That will help get an answer that exactly matches what you want to know (without getting into the full complexities of _a number of_). That will also help other people find your question.

Comment: @BenKovitz It is in the title, always was. I think the discoverability of my question is not suffering as you say, since title is the only thing others (and you too) should see before even opening this question with wonder. I will copy the exact sentence from the title to my question body now, since you clearly somehow have missed that, and so may others. I see that my question is downvoted. Since this is the only complaint I have received against the clarity of my question, I am inclined to think that this was the reason. And I find that truly unfair, in the light of these evidence.

Comment: @BenKovitz I meant adjective, good catch, thanks.

Comment: @ThoAppelsin Sorry to hear that your question got downvoted. I think it's a perfectly reasonable and useful question. Sometimes people downvote questions because they don't understand that other languages work very differently from English, or even because the questioner doesn't fully understand the topic! The phrase "number of" is famously tricky regarding grammatical number, so people might think you're asking about the tricky usages. It would be nice to write the question to exclude those, but it's OK. You got a good, correct answer, so it was a success.